# Saving userdata to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, sublimetext

The last week i have been trying to make a login system for my new website. But no matter what youtube video i download, i cant get it to the data to localhost. I have no clue what the problem is so im trying here to ask if someone knows whats wrong. So when i registrer, nothing happends like asking me to save password to chrome. And it does not save the data to my localhost database table either :( Im so confused..

Btw im on a Mac and I use Hostgator for my host and localhost as database.

heres my code for registrer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>

    <title>Login/Sign Up</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LoginOrSignUpStyle.css">

</head>



<body>

    <div>
<h1>Login or Sign Up</h1>

<center>
<p>

<ul id="menu">
<li id="items"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="LoginOrRegistrer.php">Login/Signup</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="Leaderboards.html">Leaderboards</a></l1>
<li id="items"><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a></li>

</ul>

    </p>

    </div>



    <form name="Login1" method="post" action="registrer.php">
<input type="text" id="usernamecss" name="username1" placeholder="Username" required> <br>
<input type="password" id="passwordcss" name="password1" placeholder="Password" required> <br>

</form>



<form name="Registrer1" method"post" action="registrer.php">
<input id="firstname"type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" required> <br>
<input id="lastname" type="text"  name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required> <br>
<input id="usernameregistrer" type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Username" required> <br>
<input id="email" type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Email-Adress" required> <br>
<input id="passwordregistrer" type="text"  name="password" placeholder="Password" required> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Registrer">
    </form>







<div id="main">
<p><h2>Forgotten password?</h2><p/>


<p>Game World is a brand new website created by Cilus Apps. It has hundreds of games to play, both singleplayer and multiplayer! You can play games or whatch your friends live while playing against other players!
    you can also bet who is going to win, and if you bet right, you win the money the peoples who betted wrong betted.<p>
       <p>Registrer today and join the fun! The first day is free!</p>
</div>

</center>


<p id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2017 Cilus</p>
    </body>



<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit1"])) {

    $link=mysqli_connect("host","username","password");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"users");
     mysqli_query($link,"sett inn registrerings verdia('','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')");

}

?>

</html>
```

Comment: "sett inn registrerings verdia" doesn't look like SQL at all. I would suggest to put aside video tutorials in favor of a good old paperback

Comment: Note: [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is a technical term. "Mac" is a product made by Apple.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in.

Comment: @tadman What would you write instead of $_POST ?Please someone help i have been trying to fix this for days:)

Comment: If you're depending on YouTube tutorials you're probably going to be lead astray, they're often wildly wrong or superficial and utterly useless in terms of teaching fundamentals. What you want is a framework, and more specifically one that gives you a lot of this functionality out of the box so you don't spend tons of time re-inventing the wheel. Here's a [Laravel 5.3 introduction](https://devdojo.com/series/laravel-5-3-basics/episode/introduction) that runs through the basics. Chapter 10 covers authentication, and that part is quite easy once you've absorbed the earlier material.